# How to use Instantiate to spawn objects next to Player position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making a 2D platformer where one of the core mechanics is building platforms. I was trying to use Instantiate to spawn the platforms next to the player.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class building : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject rampUpPrefab;
    public GameObject kladkaPrefab;
    public Transform Player;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Spawn()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            Instantiate(rampUpPrefab, Player.transform.position);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
        {
            Instantiate(kladkaPrefab, Player.transform.position);
        }

    }

    private void Instantiate(GameObject kladkaPrefab, Vector3 vector3)
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Spawn();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi first of all I would rename your Instantiate function to something else since its already a function that exists with UnityEngine.Object.

here 2 basic way to instantiate the prefabs

```
private void InstantiatePrefab(GameObject prefab, Vector3 position)
    {
        //Option 1. Spawn the prefab a set position and set rotation.
        GameObject.Instantiate(prefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        //Option 2. Spawn the prefab (at prefab position), you can then move it where you want
        GameObject instance = Instantiate<GameObject>(prefab);
        instance.transform.position = position;
    }
```

They both do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked for me, but I have a small question. How can I make scipt that if 20 prefabs are on the scene then something  happens? I couldn't find the answer on google.

Comment: That a bit vague but based on your code above you could have a variable like
private int numberOfPrefabs; to track how many you create then inside the InstentiatePrefab function you increment it -> numberOfPrefabs++; and finally you check it if(numberOfPreabs >= 20){ //call a function here.}